# How to distribute this logic expressions

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to prove the binary resolution proof that if I have $a \vee b$ and $ \lnot b \vee c$ then this will imply $$ a \vee c$$

Now I want to do it this way $$(a \vee b) \wedge ( \lnot b \vee c) \implies (a \vee c)$$

So i want to distribute this and among the expression to arrive at the conclusion.

I tried to apply the distribute property and hence I have $$(a \wedge  (\lnot b \vee c) \vee (b \wedge ( \lnot b \vee c))$$

and then I will have $$((a \wedge \lnot b) \vee (a \wedge c)) \vee (b \vee \lnot b) \vee (b \wedge c))   $$

I know that $$b \wedge \lnot b$$ will cancel but then How would I simplify

$$((a \wedge \lnot b) \vee (a \wedge c)) \vee (b \wedge c))   $$

? any suggestions please ! ?

Comment: The method you seem to want only works for equivalent statements and $a\lor c$ isn't equivalent to your starting formula. At some point you'll need to use some other sort of method other than the usual boolean laws. What methods are at your disposal? **N.B.:** You have a typo, it should be $b\land \neg b$ instead of $b\lor \neg b$.

Comment: If you want to show that something is a logical consequence of a disjunction (that is, a formula of the form $A_1 \vee A_2 \vee \ldots A_n$), you can do that by showing that it is a logical consequence of each of $A_1,\ldots,A_n$. 
But as Git Gud notes, how you do it depends on the methods you are allowed to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to prove that :

> $((a∨b)∧(¬b∨c)) \to (a∨c)$

is a *tautology*.

After your application of *distributivity*, we have :

> $[(a∧¬b)∨(a∧c)∨(b∧c)] \to (a∨c)$.

We can rewrite it as :

> $\lnot [(a∧¬b)∨(a∧c)∨(b∧c)] \lor (a∨c)$

that is equivalent to :

> $[(\lnot a \lor b) \land (\lnot a \lor \lnot c) \land (\lnot b \lor \lnot c)] \lor (a∨c)$.

By distributivity again, we get a conjunction of three disjuncts :

> (1) $[(\lnot a \lor b) \lor (a \lor c)] \equiv [(\lnot a \lor a) \lor (b \lor c)] \equiv T \lor (b \lor c) \equiv T$
>
> (2) $[(\lnot a \lor \lnot c) \lor (a \lor c)] \equiv [(\lnot a \lor a) \lor (\lnot c \lor c)] \equiv T \lor T \equiv T$
>
> (3) $[(\lnot b \lor \lnot c) \lor (a \lor c)] \equiv [(\lnot b \lor a) \lor (\lnot c \lor c)] \equiv (\lnot b \lor a) \lor T \equiv T$.

Thus, the original formula is equivalent to :

> > $T \land T \land T \equiv T$

i.e. it is a *tautology*, and thus we can conclude (again) that the [Resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) is *sound*.